# Let $z$ be a large parameter, let $W = \prod_{p \leq z}p$ and let $m = \frac{W}{2}$. Prove $\mathbb{Z_W^*} \cong \mathbb{Z_m^*}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here $W = \prod_{p \leq z}p$ is the product of all primes not exceeding $z$, and let $m = \frac{W}{2}$.

I am stuck trying to prove the multiplicative group of units modulo $W$, $\mathbb{Z_W^*}$ is isomorphic to the corresponding group modulo $m$, $\mathbb{Z_m^*}$.

My approach:

I know by the multiplicativity of the Euler totient function, and that $\phi(2) = 1$, that both these groups have the same cardinality. So it suffices to define an injective group homomorphism from one to the other.

Let $[x]_W$ denote the residue class of the integer $x$ modulo $W$, and let $[x]_m$ denote the residue class of the integer $x$ modulo $m$.

Let $f: \mathbb{Z_W^*} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_m^*}$ be defined as follows. $f([a]_W) = [a]_m$. This is well defined because if two integers are congruent modulo $W$, then they are also congruent modulo $m$. However this map is not injective since $f[m]_W = f[m]_m = 0$.

Comment: $\phi(W)=\prod_{p\leq z}(p-1)$ but since $2-1=1$ this is the same as $\prod_{p>2, p\leq z} (p-1)$ which is $\phi(W/2)$.